# How to Create an excel dropdown list that displays text with a numeric hidden value

Tags: excel

I am trying to create a drop down list that displays text with a hidden numerical value attached. Then I will have a standard formula on the same row that calculates a value based upon the hidden value selected.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

### Data validation drop down

There is a list option in Data validation.  If this is combined with a VLOOKUP formula you would be able to convert the selected value into a number.

The steps in Excel 2010 are:

- Create your list with matching values.
- On the **Data** tab choose **Data Validation**
- The Data validation form will be displayed
- Set the *Allow* dropdown to List
- Set the *Source* range to the first part of your list
- Click on OK (User messages can be added if required)

In a cell enter a formula like this

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,$D$3:$E$5,2,FALSE)
```

which will return the matching value from the second part of your list.

[image: Screenshot of Data validation list]

### Form control drop down

Alternatively, Form controls can be placed on a worksheet.  They can be linked to a range and return the position number of the selected value to a specific cell.

The steps in Excel 2010 are:

- Create your list of data in a worksheet
- Click on the Developer tab and dropdown on the Insert option
- In the Form section choose Combo box or List box
- Use the mouse to draw the box on the worksheet
- Right click on the box and select Format control
- The Format control form will be displayed
- Click on the Control tab
- Set the Input range to your list of data
- Set the Cell link range to the cell where you want the number of the
  selected item to appear
- Click on OK

[image: Screenshot of form control]

Comment: If only Microsoft's answers could be written this well.

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of drop down lists available (I am not sure since which version).

**ActiveX Drop Down**

You can set the column widths, so your hidden column can be set to 0.

**Form Drop Down**

You could set the drop down range to a hidden sheet and reference the cell adjacent to the selected item. This would also work with the ActiveX type control.

Comment: Hi, I like your second suggestion but how do you reference the cell adjacent to the selected item, can you give an example?