# NodeJS and MySQL: Importing CSV data with associations

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I've searched the web and I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33911597/how-to-insert-foreign-key-in-sequelize-model) which might be related with my question but as I do not understand, I've come this to ask.

I'm trying to insert data into tables. I'm using `sequelize v6` and `mysql`.

**What I have in my database**

I've 2 tables, student and township.

student table: `id, name, email, township_id`

township table: `id, name`

**What I have in my associations**

Student Model

```
Student.belongsTo(models.Township, {
    foreignKey: "townshipId",
    as: "township",
});
```

Township Model

```
Township.hasMany(models.Student, {
    foreignKey: "townshipId",
    as: "township",
});
```

**What I have in req**:

In my req, I have data like below:

```
{
    name: 'john',
    email: 'john@gmail.com',
    township: 'Flank',
}
```

**Question**

Actually, I'm trying to bulk insert csv data into my database. The end-users will fill data into excel with like the above data (in the req) and save as csv file and import it to the system. The problem is the value I get from parsing csv is township name as `text value`, in this case `Flank`. But I do need to change it to `integer` township_id so that I can insert into `students` table with that township_id.

(What I have done: I grab the township name in this case `Flank` and run query `SELECT township_id FROM townships WHERE name = 'Flank'`, and I get township_id back if the `Flank` is there in townships table. So, I can now use that township_id in inserting into `students` table. But I think it is very costly and another fact is that I also have another 50 fields like this.)

Therefore, my question is that how can I insert that `township: 'Flank'` into `students` table without explicitly finding `township_id` first (avoiding what I've done).

Thank you.

Comment: Do you want to create a new township in `township` table, a new student in `student` table, and their relationship?

Comment: No. I want to insert with associations. Actually, I was working on importing CSV via the system. In the CSV, the end-user will choose the township's name from the drop-down. So the value I get from parsing CSV is like in my req in the question. But when I actually insert that data into the students table, I need to map or associate the township_id which is equalized with Flank and insert it. @slideshowp2

Comment: not sure, but maybe [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8295816/how-to-create-an-excel-dropdown-list-that-displays-text-with-a-numeric-hidden-va) could help you. Instead of handling the data on runtime(while processing and inserting), fix the problem at the source and fix the dropdown behavior, so that the user will select the text but in the sheet the id will be selected.

Comment: @RaghavGarg Thanks. I thought that way but I'm not sure it is suitable to put those kind of data in Excel (what I mean is to hide those real data columns because the end-users can accidentally delete that column or whatever) and as I search in web, I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42494410/importing-csv-data-into-rails-app-using-something-other-then-the-association-i)  which does the mapping inside models. So, I'm wondering how can I achieve this in sequelize. But thank you for your comment.

Comment: This appraoch may not work for a large dataset, but you can maybe load the full data of townships in memory using a single SQL query and convert it into a hash with township's name as a key so that for every student record you can get the township_id in O(1) from memory only.

Comment: *Actually, I'm trying to bulk insert csv data into my database. The end-users will fill data into excel with like the above data (in the req) and save as csv file and import it to the system.* If so then your question is not related to node.js and sequelize.js, it is pure MySQL-related. So the only data needed REALLY is: complete CREATE TABLE for your tables, sample initial data (2-3 rows) as INSERT INTO, sample CSV file comntent (2-3 rows), desired tables state after importing. The answer will be according LOAD DATA INFILE statement.

Comment: @Akina It depends on how you see. Yes, the question is related to ONLY MySQL if you fill the historical bulk data. But that's not what I need. The end-users will constantly upload CSV files as they use the System. Sorry for the misunderstanding but that's why I mentioned `...and import it to the system.` Therefore, I think it is CLOSELY related to the programming languages used.

Comment: I.e. you want to parse this CSV on the script level and save into the tables row-by-row?

Comment: Yes. I want to map the text value with ids and insert into the tables. But I'm wondering which is a better approach: creating hidden columns in excel (csv) or mapping inside code level. Those are mentioned by @RaghavGarg above.

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is the value I get from parsing csv is township name as text value, in this case `Flank`. But I do need to change it to integer `township_id` so that I can insert into `students` table with that `township_id`.

For this, instead of

```
INSERT INTO students (name   , township, ...)
    VALUES           ('John' , 'Flank' , ...)
```

you must use

```
INSERT INTO students (name   , township_id, ...)
    SELECT            'John' , township_id, ...
    FROM towns
    WHERE town_name = 'Flank';
```

---

PS. I don't know how `INSERT .. SELECT` is performed in script/framework syntax.